# How to copy one row in a .csv file to another row with python

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to merge the strings from the first two rows of a .csv file into one row in python.
I am using a file with over 150 columns.

Right now it looks like this:

1. ;; Test1; Test1; Test1; Test 2; Test 2; Test2
2. Name;Birthday; Points Q1; Points Q2; Points Q3; Points Q1; Points Q2; Points Q3

but I need to merge the information into one row, that looks like this:

1. Name;Birthday;Test1 PointsQ1; Test1 Points Q2; Test1 Points Q3; Test2 Points Q1;...

Answer (score 1):

Using the pandas library you can do this,

First of installing the pandas library if you don't have,

By using this command

```
pip install pandas
```

Then add this script in your code

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("YOUR FILE LOCATION WITH FILE NAME")
```

This line will print you the first row of your excel sheet

```
print(data.ioc[0])
```

You can combine the first two rows into one row and save in the first row

```
data.iloc[0]=[data.iloc['YOUR COLUMN NAME'][0]+data.iloc['YOUR COLUMN NAME'][1],data.iloc[]+.......]
```

Like this for your every column and it will save in the first row 
And Run a loop for remaining rows and update it.

For saving from the data variable that is data frame  TO CSV

```
data.to_csv('your-file-name.csv', sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to do it by converting the .csv file into an array.

```
def addheader(inputfile):

 results = []
 with open(inputfile, "r") as r:
      reader = csv.reader(r, delimiter=';')
          for row in reader:
           i = i+1
           if i < x:
                results.append(row)


      i = 0
      x = len(results[0])-1

      while i < x:
           i = i+1
           results[1][i] = results[0][i] + " " + results[1][i]
```